# Why doesn't my React Component render it's return statements JSX?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

This image depicts the `svg` displayed on the screen and in the DOM but in a component other than the one it's supposed to be. The sibling `div class="timeline"`has the same `svg` in the source code but it isn't displayed on screen nor in the DOM as we can see here.
[image]An `svg` of a line is supposed to be displayed, and it actually is when it's passed to a different component, but when passed to the Timeline component it doesn't appear even in the DOM. What's wrong?

This is the file that imports and displays the component that contains the SVG element to be displayed.

```js
import './App.css';
import Timeline from './components/Timeline';
import Reminders from './components/Reminders';
import MoneyBuddy from './components/MoneyBuddy';
// import {Calc} from './components/Calc';
import Calc from './components/Calculator';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Timeline />
      <Reminders />
      <MoneyBuddy />
      <Calc />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the component that's passed to the above code. What's weird is that the same svg element can be placed in another component's return statement and is displayed in the DOM and on the screen. But this component doesn't appear even in the DOM.

```js
import React from "react"

function Timeline() {
    return(
      <div className="timeline">
       <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <line x1="0" x2="100" y1="50" y2="50" stroke="orange"></line>
        </svg>
      </div>
      );
}

export default Timeline
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I took a look at the CSS to see if any position or display properties may be conflicting are causing the issue but can't tell. Can anyone else see what's wrong?

```css
body {
  background-color: #202020;
}

.App {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "timelineGridArea timelineGridArea timelineGridArea"
  "money-buddyGridArea remindersGridArea calcGridArea";
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.timeline{
  grid-area: timelineGridArea;
}

.money-buddy{
  grid-area: money-buddyGridArea;
}

.reminders{
  grid-area: remindersGridArea;
  position: relative;
}

.calc{
  grid-area: calcGridArea;
}

.App > div {
  width: 99%;
  height: 355px;
  color: #38ed38;
  margin: 1px;
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: relative;

/*border*/ overflow: hidden; /* cuts corners off rotating animation */
}

.App > div::after{
  content: ""; /* places gradient tile behind grid-area */
  position: absolute;
  background: #202020;
/*border*/inset: 1px; /*makes the front div a little smaller than the back div */
}

.App > div::before{
/*border*/ content: ""; /*gives space to the back div to appear */
/*border*/ position: absolute;
/*border*/ width: 100%;
/*border*/ height: 100%;
/*border*/ background: linear-gradient(#00ccff, #d400d4);
/*border*/ animation: animate 125s linear infinite;
}

/*border*/@keyframes animate {
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're using runnable snippets, make sure that the snippet actually works, and that you've removed the parts that don't contribute to the problem: CSS is irrelevant if the problem is a render() not kicking in, those other components are irrelevant if the problem is the `TimeLine` component, and splitting it up as multiple runnables is definitely not going to work. Just make one runnable snippet, put your TimeLine and your App in it, and add just enough code around it to actually run your app.

Comment: The claim that the element is not in the dom seems unlikely with the snippets you've shared. It might not be visible due to css, but still in the dom, Or maybe you've missed a console error?
Could you share a codesandbox where the issue also occurs? i'm not able to reproduce in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-boyd-okkpph?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I just tried the code you provided and it works normally. As other comments suggested you can replicate the issue, but it is very likely your problem is related to the other components or your project configuration.